# Why can't Swift find a Float extension method when called on an integer literal?

Tags: swift

I have defined a method on `Float` called `printme`, and when I try to call it with an *integer literal*, Swift fails to find the method:

```
extension Float {
    func printme() {
        print("value: \(self)")
    }
}

12.printme()    // error: value of type 'Int' has no member 'printme'
```

If I use an explicit cast it works:

```
(12 as Float).printme()  // prints "value: 12.0"
```

**Why, if Float conforms to the *IntegerLiteralConvertible* protocol, does `12.printme()` fail to find the method on `Float`?**  It works if the type
is `Double`, but fails for `Int32`, `UInt`, and other types.  **Why does it work for `Double`, but not for `Float`?**

Note that the following does work:

```
func printit(f: Float) {
    print("value: \(f)")
}

printit(10)              // prints "value: 10.0"
```

So, it fails when the method is called on the *integer literal* but not when the *integer literal* is a parameter to a function.

---

In **Xcode 6.4** it fails in a different way:

```
12.printme()  // error: cannot invoke 'printme' with no arguments
```

Comment: try Float(10).printme()

Comment: @Lucho, `Float(10).printme()` works fine as does the explicit cast `(10 as Float)`.  I'm wondering why Swift needs that extra information and can't figure it out for itself since `Float` conforms to *IntegerLiteralConvertible*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't have an explicit type, Swift assumes either `Int` or `Double`. From the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309):

> For example, if you assign a literal value of 42 to a new constant without saying what type it is, Swift infers that you want the constant to be an `Int`, because you have initialized it with a number that looks like an integer ... Likewise, if you don’t specify a type for a floating-point literal, Swift infers that you want to create a `Double`.

`Float` is not on the inferred type list for literals. If you change your extension to Double, it works (Xcode 7.1):

```
extension Double {
    func printme() {
        print("I'm a Double")
    }
}

12.printme()
12.0.printme()
```

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of extensions I look for protocols all types I want to affect conform too, instead of counting on it that the compiler will play nice and convert `Double` to `Float` and the other way around.

`IntegerLiteralConvertible` works for all, but then you have no access to the numeric value. If you add a constraint to either `IntegerType` or `FloatingPointType` you have access to `toIntMax()` and `self.advancedBy(0)`

```
extension IntegerLiteralConvertible where Self : IntegerType {
    func printMe() {
        print(self.toIntMax())
    }
}

extension IntegerLiteralConvertible where Self : FloatingPointType {
    func printMe() {
        print(self.advancedBy(0))
    }
}


let float = Float(10.234234)
float.printMe()

let double = Double(234.234234)
double.printMe()

let int = Int(234234)
int.printMe()

let int16 = Int16(234)
int16.printMe()
```

Comment: Still doesn't explain the _why_. One could assume that the compiler would magically assume the literal to be a float and use the method the OP wants, but that's not happening and OP wants to know why, not how to work around it.

Comment: @DarkDust the why is nicely explained in the other answer. Explaining it again by essentially copy pasting would not be nice to do.

Comment: If you can explain it in a better way, it _is_ nice :-)