# Ambiguous use of operator '-' in Swift with 'abs()'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var i = -(abs(-3))
```

or

```
var i = -abs(-3)
```

or

```
var i = -abs(3)
```

or

```
var i = -(abs(3))
```

But I get an error saying that use of minus is ambiguous. Why?

Comment: You could try `abs(-3) * -1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a compiler bug to me, the type of the literal `3`
should be `Int`. But the compiler complains

```
error: ambiguous use of operator '-'
var i = -(abs(-3))
        ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Float) -> Float
                   ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Double) -> Double
                   ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Float80) -> Float80
                   ^
CoreGraphics.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

You can solve it with an explicit `Int` as parameter:

```
var i = -(abs(-Int(3)))
```

or with a type annotation on the result:

```
var i : Int = -(abs(-3))
```

As @vacawama noticed, there are more possible solutions.
Casting *any* subexpression to `Int` makes the compiler happy:

```
var i1 = -(abs(-(3 as Int)))
var i2 = -(abs((-3) as Int))
var i3 = -(abs(-3) as Int)
var i4 = -(abs(-3)) as Int
```

Comment: We humans tend to think of this from the inside out.  `3` is an `Int`, so `-3` is of course an `Int`, `abs` takes an `Int` and returns and `Int` and unary `-` is defined on `Int` so this should work.  The Swift compiler is probably approaching from the other direction ... unary minus works on all of these types, `abs` returns this subset of types, `abs` takes these possible types as input, and `3` can be any of a bunch of types due to `integerLiteralConvertible`, so by adding unary `-` to the expression Swift starts with a broad range of types and is never able to narrow it down to one.

Comment: @vacawama: But then `var i = abs(-3)`  would also be ambiguous (but is isn't)

Comment: that is a good point.  Swift seems to go out of its way sometimes to find problems that just aren't there.  I had the opposite frustration in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34068570/1630618

Comment: let i: Int = -abs(-3) should be perfectly valid, i hope so ... :-)

Comment: The problem seems to be with unary minus.  This even fails: `var i = -(3)`

Comment: And `var i = -(3+2)` reports **error: ambiguous use of operator '+'**

Comment: @vacawama: That's interesting! You might consider to post your observations as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @MartinR that this looks like a compiler bug.  So where is the problem?

My experiments point toward *unary minus* being the culprit.  Note that even:

```
var i = -(3)
```

fails with:

```
error: ambiguous use of operator '-'
var i = -(3)
        ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Float) -> Float
                   ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Double) -> Double
                   ^
Swift.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: Float80) -> Float80
                   ^
CoreGraphics.-:2:20: note: found this candidate
prefix public func -(x: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> CoreGraphics.CGFloat**
```

---

This simple expression:

```
var i = -(3 + 2)
```

fails with:

```
error: ambiguous use of operator '+'
var i = -(3 + 2)
            ^
Swift.+:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func +(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
            ^
Swift.+:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func +(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
            ^
Swift.+:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func +(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
            ^
CoreGraphics.+:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func +(lhs: CoreGraphics.CGFloat, rhs: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> CoreGraphics.CGFloat
```

---

Each time, the four types **Float**, **Double**, **Float80**, and **CoreGraphics.CGFloat** are the types Swift is having trouble deciding amongst.  Why just these four?  **Why isn't Int in there?**  Especially since Swift defaults to treating an integer literal as an `Int`.