# Absolute value function abs() unavailable in Swift 3.0. Use abs(_:) free function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I am converting a Swift iOS project to Swift 3.0 using Xcode 8 Beta 4. The absolute value function shows to be unavailable. Here is a code sample...

```
let myInt = -3
let myAbsoluteInt = abs(myInt)
```

The second line results in an error stating: `'abs' is unavailable: Please use the 'abs(_:)' free function`.

Ideas?

Comment: *Your code works in Xcode 8 beta 4*. I suppose you have another issue causing this misleading error message. What are your imports? Maybe there's a conflict. Also "clean" your project. // A *quick workaround* could be to use the complete type: `let myAbsoluteInt = Swift.abs(myInt)`.

Comment: Seems to be [working fine](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57a36665febcdeea752f2edc)

Comment: @EricAya, you were correct.  There was a conflict.  Swift.abs(myInt) solved it.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricAya No problem closing it, but I don't see that reason as selectable.  What about just deleting the question?

Comment: Well nevermind, I thought the information about the complete type as a workaround could be useful so I've made an answer from my comment. You can still force close the question if you prefer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code you're showing us works for me in Xcode 8 beta 4.

I suppose you have another, different issue causing this misleading error message.

For example, it could be a conflict if you have imported other libraries.

A quick *workaround* would be to use the complete type:

```
let myAbsoluteInt = Swift.abs(myInt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try explicit `Int` as parameter as mentioned here it may be a bug :
[Ambiguous use of operator '-' in Swift with 'abs()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239941/ambiguous-use-of-operator-in-swift-with-abs)

```
let myInt:Int = -3
let myAbsoluteInt = abs(myInt)
```

Comment: how do you do this the opposite way around. Make the positive integer negative?

Comment: @AdrianGutierrez, you would use the unary "-" operator on the absolute value: let myAlwaysNegativeInt = -abs(myInt)

Comment: awesome! Thanks @conarch